# Binary optimization search

Tags: java, optimization, binary-search

I'm trying to write a function to optimize a function using binary subdivision. The idea is that I can pass it the lower and upper bounds to test and it will return the lowest value of n that returns 'true' from the function.

```
public interface BinaryTest {
    boolean test(int n);
}

/**
 * Returns the smallest int in the set lower <= n <= upper that returns true for
 * {@link BinaryTest#test(int)}. If a value 'n' returns true, then any value
 * > 'n' will also return true.
 *
 * If none of the values return true, return -1.
 */
int optimizeSmallest(int lower, int upper, BinaryTest testFunction) {
    // ???
}
```

While examples of binary search are common, this is more difficult to find patterns for and I feel like it's easy to end up with an off-by-one error.

What would the optimizeSmallest function look like?

Simple testcase:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int j = i;
        int r = BinarySearch.optimizeSmallest(0, 10, (n) -> {
            return n > j;
        });

        assertEquals(i + 1, r);
    }
```

Comment: You would still do a binary search for this problem. Just ensure that eventually you'll end up the with the case where your `lower == upper - 1`. In that case, `testFunction.test(lower)` returns false and `testFunction.test(upper)` returns true. You would return upper as your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int optimizeSmallest(int lower, int upper, BinaryTest testFunction) {
    if (lower > upper || !testFunction.test(upper)) {
        return -1;
    }
    while (lower != upper) {
        int middle = (lower + upper) / 2;
        if (testFunction.test(middle)) {
            upper = middle;
        } else {
            lower = middle + 1;
        }
    }
    return lower;
}
```

Comment: Bingo. This one works, but it shares the same problem as the answer I put above -- it'll test the final answer twice in some cases. Do you think it is possible to avoid that double-test? Example: BinarySearch.optimizeSmallest(0, 10, (n) -> {
   System.out.println(n);
   return n > 0;
  })

Comment: @slipheed Now it's optimal - once we are sure that the answer is not -1, we will check the returned integer only once.

Comment: @slipheed : i tried to contact you on wordpress forum about the license software manager thread you started. Would it be possible to get a c# sample on how to activate a license with a c# app. I have not been to get it to work...

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
int optimizeSmallest(int lower, int upper, BinaryTest testFunction) {
    if(lower >= upper) {
        return upper;
    }
    int mid = (low + high) >>> 1;
    return testFunction.test(mid) ? optimizeSmallest(lower, mid, testFunction) 
        : optimizeSmallest(mid, upper, testFunction);
}
```

Comment: This throws a StackOverflowException when I run it on a simple testcase.

Answer (score 1):

This is not optimal (it will test the final value a second time in some cases), but appears to work for all test cases I've thrown at it. I'll leave it here until someone posts an answer that works better than this one.

```
public static int optimizeSmallest(int lower, int upper, BinaryTest testFunction) {
    while (lower < upper) {
        int mid = (lower + upper) >>> 1;

        if (testFunction.test(mid))
            upper = mid;
        else
            lower = mid + 1;
    }

    return testFunction.test(lower) ? lower : -1;
}
```